# How to edit .css file from html via jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to change attribute properties in a style.css file using a jquery onclick event from html file?

I am using the below currently, but I would like to change the css file itself.

```
$('#demo').click(function(){
    $(.#demo').slideUp();
     this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});
```

Comment: I dont think you can modify css inspite you can add a attribute to an element something like  $('#demo').css("background-color" , "red");

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot edit the file itself. However, you can override styles a number of ways.

1. Create a new `style` element with the required rules and append to the document. ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/eVA94/))
2. Select elements and apply [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to change the desired properties. ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/sHRKV/1/))
3. Define CSS selectors (possibly in concert with #1 above), and add or remove them from items using `.addClass` and `.removeClass`. ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/PPbkm/1/))

For the type of behavior you describe, you'd use #2 or #3 (#3 is recommended because it's the easiest to maintain). Here's #2 in practice using your example: http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/HTNGs/1/

```
$('#demo').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot edit css file itself but can change or add css propreties.

Here is a DEMO to help YOU http://jsfiddle.net/Simplybj/EFsvz/2/

You can add muliple css properties to your html like

```
   $('#demo').click(function(){
        $(this).css({'background-color':'red','color':'white');
    });
```

Or if you have css Class defined in style sheet like

```
.makeRed
{
    background-color:red;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin:5px;
}
 .makeGreen{
    background-color:green;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin:5px;
}
```

And Markup like

```
<div id="me" class="makeRed"></div>
```

Then You can change class of div  as

```
$('#me').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('makeRed').addClass('makeGreen');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot edit css file, if you want to edit css property/attribute then you have to use like this

```
$(this).css("name","value");
```

so for you, it will be `$(this).css("background-color","red");` instead of  `this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';`

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit the CSS file using only jquery, but you can create a php script that can open/save the file, then pass the css changes to that script with jquery.

Checkout this link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit files on the server from the client-side.

This is simply not possible due to security reasons, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is an other method, define separate css classes with your changed and unchanged properties. Then using j query/ java script you can easily change class of the element.
Hope it will work...